# Does kdenlive have a limit regarding the workable filesize?

Tags: kde, video-editing, kdenlive

Does kdenlive have a limit regarding the workable file-size?

Comment: if you're talking about segfaults, it completely depends on your cpu, ram, etc. i suggest setting the *default profile* as low as possible and working up from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about kdenlive, but when using Cinelerra the max file size was only limited by the file system (ie. ext3 upper limit).
I would be surprised if you hit any limit, but that is depending on how you split up your clips.
http://www.kdenlive.org/forum/working-many-gb-data-one-project has a bit more info, but I think your RAM is going to have more effect than any programmatic limitations.

If you are referring to the old windows limit of 2GB file sizes no this is not in effect on linux.

If you need to break up a large VOB file for prosessing, you can use ffmpeg (more details here: https://superuser.com/questions/31135/split-mpeg-video-from-command-line )

Comment: I tried to cut some pieces from a 6,6 gigabyte vob-file but I couldn't find the last part of the movie (the closing credits at the end were there). Now I retried it and and it worked. Don't know what went wrong in the first place.

Comment: It didn't work - it was only another part which was missing. I think your note with the ram was the right track. I don't have experience in video-editing so I guess the file must fit into the memory (the PC has 4 GB).